# Apply function on pandas using the index

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1=[i for i in range(10)]
col2=[i**2 for i in range(10)]
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1,col2)),columns=['col1','col2'])
```

I want to create a new column using apply that adds the numbers in each row and then it adds then index. Something like

```
df['col3']=df.apply(lambda x:x['col1']+x['col2']+index(x))
```

But of course index(x) does not work.

How can I do it in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is possible with `axis=1` and `x.name`, but because loops it is slow:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] + x['col2'] + x.name, axis=1)
```

Vectorized solution is add `df.index`:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df.index
```

Performance in 10k sample data:

```
N = 10000
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(N),
                 'col2':np.arange(N) ** 2})



In [234]: %timeit df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] + x['col2'] + x.name, axis=1)
131 ms ± 4.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [235]: %timeit df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df.index
654 µs ± 90.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I was about to update with the `x.name` and `axis=1` I'll leave it like this

Comment: So lambda is that much more efficient compared to vectors? I don't see the why but good to know.

My case is not that simple so I need to use lambda anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a function for such a simple case, a vectorized addition will be much more efficient:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1']+df['col2']+df.index
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     0     0     0
1     1     1     3
2     2     4     8
3     3     9    15
4     4    16    24
5     5    25    35
6     6    36    48
7     7    49    63
8     8    64    80
9     9    81    99
```